# Segfault when using arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o, no problems without -o

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile some code to run on an ARM Cortex A8 (the AR.Drone 2.0, if it makes a difference).

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit on my Virtualbox (with Windows 7 64-bit host), and my cross-compiled code works perfectly fine.

On another computer, I installed the same version of Ubuntu (without Virtualbox), but I'm encountering weird errors. The smallest code snippet I've gotten that demonstrates the problem is a "hello world" program (I can show the code here if necessary):

- I've executed: **sudo apt-get install g++ gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi g++-arm-linux-gnueabi**
- When I run **arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ hello.cpp**, the cross-compiled code (a.out) works fine on the ARM.
- When I run **arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o hello hello.cpp**, I get a segfault when executing hello on the ARM.
- I've compared the outputs of **file hello** and **read-elf -A hello** when compiled with Virtualbox and without, and they look identical.
- I don't have gdb on the ARM, so I can't gdb it to find out where the segfault is coming from.

Any ideas/solutions would be greatly appreciated. I did not have to set up anything special on my Virtualbox, so I'm quite confused why the PC without Virtualbox cannot cross-compile correctly.

Comment: try to check dmesg (cat /proc/kmsg) or if you can use strace to see where it is failing.

Comment: For a simple "hello world", comparing the disassembly (arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -d) is also a viable option.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Filezilla or the like make sure that you are not using "auto" as transfer mode. Choose "binary", I had the very same problem transferring a simple hello world program from my ubuntu to an arm target (Xilinx Zynq) and after hours spent investigating I checked the md5 of the executable both on ubuntu and the target discovering that they were different.

Comment: You just ended my 3 day streak of frustration in not understanding why suddenly my linux build failed to run, thanks for mentioning this

Answer (score 0):

have you tried debugging the seg fault using gdb or similar?

build your code in debug mode (output debug symbols), and follow the steps described [here](http://mytechrants.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/debugging-a-segmentation-fault-using-gdb/)

the call stack is particularly useful.

The chances are that there is a run time dependency missing in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, even on two machines (a VM and a direct install), and I was not able to solve it yet.

However, the following "workaround" worked for me (this essentially installs the ARM Toolchain by *Mentor Graphics*, formerly known as *Code Sourcery*, to cross-compile for the AR Drone 2):

- Download "arm-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.bin" from [here](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/)
- Install it by typing (needs `sudo` if you want to install to system dirs)

  ```
  $ chmod +x arm-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.bin
  $ ./arm-2012.03-57-arm-none-linux-gnueabi.bin
  ```

  and step through the (graphical) setup.
- Finally, compile your sources with the binaries located in

  ```
  $INSTALL_PATH/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/
  ```

  For example:

  ```
  ./arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a hello.c -o helloworld
  ```

  The resulting binary should be executable w/o any problems. ;-)

For the sake of completeness / all other readers: You can copy the binary to the Drone by using any FTP client (e. g., `ftp`, WinSCP, FileZilla, ...) connecting to 192.168.1.1 (assumes your host has connected to the WLAN created by the Drone). To execute it, set the executable bit by `chmod +x helloworld` and run it `./helloworld`.

BTW: There isn't a "debugger" on the AR Drone 2 but you can use gdb remote debugging by starting `gdbserver` on the device (this tool is already on the device), see (e. g.) http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_130.html